# Do I need to close a urllib.request.urlopen connection in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, python-2.x, urllib3

I'm working with the `urllib.request` module in Python 3.

My question is:

Do we need to close the connection if I open it using  `urllib.request.ulropen`?

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the documentation for [urllib.request.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html)

It states that

> urllib.request module uses HTTP/1.1 and includes Connection:close
> header in its HTTP requests.

and when we check this against Request for Comments for the HTTP protocol:

[From RFC 2616, Section 14.10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.10)

> HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to
> signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the
> response. For example,
>
> `Connection: close`
>
> in either the request or the response header
> fields indicates that the connection SHOULD NOT be considered
> `persistent' (section 8.1) after the current request/response is
> complete.
>
> HTTP/1.1 applications that do not support persistent connections MUST
> include the "close" connection option in every message.

So you don't need to close the connection. The connection is closed as soon as you receive your response

Comment: In this case, can you explain why [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/urllib2.html) advocates using a with-statement to open a url with the `urllib.request.urlopen()` function?